# Should I define model class functions for repeated controller codes in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use the code like that repeatedly in my controllers:

```
    ...    
    if (Cache::has('user_' . $id)) {
        $user = Cache::get('user_' . $id);
    } else {            
        $user = User::with('location')->find($id);
        if(!$user) {
            return Response::view('errors/404', array());
        }
        Cache::put('user_' . $id, $user, 15);
    }
    ...
```

Is it best practice to place them in Model classes as a class function? So that I would write just one line:

```
$user = User::getUserDetails($id);
```

And in model classes:

```
public function getUserDetails($id)
{        
    if(Cache::has('user_' . $id)) {
        $user = Cache::get('user_' . $id);
    } else {            
        $user = User::with('location')->find($id);
        if(!$user) {
            return Response::view('errors/404', array());
        }
        Cache::put('user_' . $id, $user, 15);
    }
    return $user;
}
```

What do you suggest?

Comment: I often use helpers for something like this. e.g. a trait or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, either use Helpers or just put it in one controller.

You just need to set it as static function.

```
public static function getUserDetails($id)
{        
    if(Cache::has('user_' . $id)) {
        $user = Cache::get('user_' . $id);
    } else {            
        $user = User::with('location')->find($id);
        if(!$user) {
            return Response::view('errors/404', array());
        }
        Cache::put('user_' . $id, $user, 15);
    }
    return $user;
}
```

If you use Helpers.

```
use Helpers;
Helpers::getUserDetails($id);
```

If you use Controller.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\TheControllerName;
TheControllerName::getUserDetails($id)
```

Comment: Isn't it better to define Model function instead of Helper? It seems to me it is more object oriented approach.

Comment: It's up to you actually. Also, you may define Model function if you think you only need it in your specific controller linked to that model.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a repository for reusable code.
Make a repository in app/Repositories/UserRepository.php

```html
<?php 
namespace App\Repositories;

use App/User;

/**
 * Class UserRepository
 *
 * @package App\Repositories
 */
class UserRepository
{
 public static function getUserDetails($id)
 {        
     if(Cache::has('user_' . $id)) {
         $user = Cache::get('user_' . $id);
     } else {            
         $user = User::with('location')->find($id);
         if(!$user) {
             return Response::view('errors/404', array());
         }
         Cache::put('user_' . $id, $user, 15);
     }
     return $user;
 }
}

In your controller, You can use like this:

<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Repositories\UserRepository;

class UserController extends Controller
{
 protected $user_repo;
 public function __construct(UserRepository $user)
        {
             ..
  $this->user_repo = $seo;
  ..
        }

        public function YourFunctionName()
        {
          ..
          $this->user_repo->getUserDetails($id);
          ..
        }

}
```

Please let me know for any confusion!